# synchronise file with 2 linux apache servers in a bidirectional way

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, bash, load-balancing, rsync

I have 2 apache servers working like a load balancer for a website, i used rsync before but rsync command is only one way direction, so if the master server goes down the slave will replace it with the loading but once the master will be back in place it will not have the slave serevr data.

Is there any way to synchronize the 2 server in a bidirectional way, so the most updated server will update also the other server?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What happens when a file is updated on both hosts at the same time?

Comment: When the primary dies the secondary takes over and becomes primary.  When you replace primary/primary comes back online it gets brought in as a/the secondary.

Answer (score 2):

Use a single datastore as an NFS mount or similar and mount it to both hosts.

or for a sloppier solution use rsync with the --update flag on both servers...

Comment: rsync and the phrase 'the most updated server'  is a recipe for disaster - lets not even mention database transactions. you need to cluster all the way down.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you run rsync on the primary server before starting Apache. But make sure you properly assess what can happen in the case of a split brain situation.